# QIcon is always showed as 2x dpi

Tags: c++, qt, dpi

I have an additional window with one text edit + qicon inside (I call it Floating Edit). 
I have 2 qicons - for usual DPI (16 x 16 icon) and it's 2x version (32 x 32). 
Names are correct - they are like icon.png and icon@2x.png. 
I need to grab pixmap from my icon and feed it to the 3rd party library. 
I cant feed qicon directly and qpixmap does not respect dpi in my qt version (5.6.2), so I have to convert with respect to dpi. 
Here is my code:

```
// ...
auto icon = QIcon(imageName);
auto availSizes = icon.availableSizes();
auto size = pFloatingEdit->window()->devicePixelRatio() == 1 ? availSizes.first() : availSizes.last();

auto pxm = icon.pixmap(size);
auto w = pxm.width();
auto h = pxm.height();
// ... <feeding to 3rd party>
```

The problem is I always get w and h equal to 32 but size variable respects dpi and returns 16 x 16 in case of 100% dpi and 32 x 32 in case of 200%. 
Could anyone please help me with that issue?

Comment: It is n error to use `==` operator for comparing float numbers.

Comment: pFloatingEdit->window()->devicePixelRatio() returns int. It calls devicePixelRatio from QPaintDevice

Comment: Do you have two monitors with different pixel ratio? ( one retina and one non retina? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set set device pixel ratio yourself.

When using multiple monitors with different pixel ratio, QPixmap does not work correctly. Maybe it is your problem. Because then devicePixelRatio in QPixmaps is always the highest from monitors. But information from QWindow is correct. So settings devicePixelRatio from QWindow should fix this.

```
auto icon = QIcon(imageName);
int pixelRatio = pFloatingEdit->window()->devicePixelRatio();
auto pxm = icon.pixmap(size);
pxm.setDevicePixelRatio(pixelRatio);
```